# Unable to set the endpoint for Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am not able to set the endpoint for an Alexa Skill.
I have followed this tutorial:
[Linking Netatmo Weather Station to Amazon Echo (Alexa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859826/linking-netatmo-weather-station-to-amazon-echo-alexa)

At the step 6 : "In the Endpoint field you need to give in the ARN" but there is not field for me to enter the ARN endpoint, Please see attached screenshot.
[image: screenShot from Amazon]

[image: After selecting AWS ARN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the AWS ARN endpoint option, then it will show you the field where you enter the ARN.

Comment: Yes, I have done that but there is only the Location field that i can Choose between America and Europe and no endpoint field. Please look at the new screenshot added. Thank you

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I was under impression that i have to put the country there